# node-sass: including font files as part of compilation process

Tags: css, angular, sass, node-sass

I'm using node-sass to bundle up a custom theme which includes pulling in a `_fonts.scss` including various font-faces such as:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url("../fonts/roboto-v15-latin-300.eot"); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'),
       url("../fonts/roboto-v15-latin-300.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url("../fonts/roboto-v15-latin-300.woff2") format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url("../fonts/roboto-v15-latin-300.woff") format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url("../fonts/roboto-v15-latin-300.ttf") format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url("../fonts/roboto-v15-latin-300.svg#Roboto") format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

In my final compiled css I see:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url("../fonts/roboto-v15-latin-300.eot");
  /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local("Roboto Light"), local("Roboto-Light"), url("../fonts/roboto-v15-latin-300.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/roboto-v15-latin-300.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/roboto-v15-latin-300.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/roboto-v15-latin-300.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/roboto-v15-latin-300.svg#Roboto") format("svg");
  /* Legacy iOS */ }
```

But when I include this in my application (using Angular CLI), it fails to compile as it tries to resolve the path to these images relative to my application directory.

e.g

> (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError:
>   /Users/robert.parker/Documents/Github/nepal-ng-common-components/projects/ng-generic-components/dist/theme-light.css:48:70: Can't resolve '../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2' in
>   '/Users/robert.parker/Documents/Github/nepal-ng-common-components/projects/ng-generic-components/dist'

I could copy the fonts folder to my target dist folder prior to bundling the css, is that the only solution here? Or could I do something like inline the font files, e.g. base64 encoded version?

Theme directory structure:

```
theme-roller/
- assets
  - fonts/
  - sass/
    - theme/
      _theme.scss
    _fonts.scss
  - theme/
    - theme.scss
```

**theme.scss**

```
@import '../sass/theme/_theme';
```

_theme.scss

```
@import '../_fonts';
```

Comment: Are the fonts located in assets folder?

Comment: @JosefKatič - yes they are, I have updated my question with the directory structure I have setup currently